# DynamoDB: Sorting and filtering index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table **Threads** with **id** (number), **last_message** (number) and **is_valid** (number).

I want to get results where `is_valid = 1` and sorted by `last_message` asc (or desc).

I set id as partition key (hash), is_valid as sort key and then created a global secondary index named "lastMessageValidIndex" where the partition key is is_valid and the sort key is last_message, but it's not working.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to query lastMessageValidIndex. query for `is_valid = 1` and you should get results ordered by `last_message`

Comment: I tried to set IndexName to lastMessageValidIndex but the order not changed. Have you got an example of the structure and of the query?

Comment: the name of the secondary index is not matter. you just need to query secondary index. dynamodb sorts the result for you. so if you get results then your query is ok, but maybe your index scheme is wrong.

Comment: For this reason I asked. With "I set the IndexName" I was talking about the param of the query.

Answer (score 0):

One of the difficulties with noSQL (and thus also DynamoDB) is that you cannot just query on everything. You can only query on an index and an index must be unique (the hash-range combination). If there are two rows with the same `last_valid` and `last_message` value, only one will be inserted in the GSI.

The partition key `is_valid` only has a few variables (probably only 0 and 1), which hurts partitioning (hence the name). If the db is heavily used you will get into problems (see also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions ).

If `is_valid` is not changed relatively often, you might consider creating 2 tables: one with only valid and one with only invalid threads. Then you can query on the primary key in the correct table. When `is_valid` is toggled, you simply move the record from one table to another.

Comment: Luc, thank you. Have you got an idea? I figured out that I can't Scan because then I can't use ScanIndexForward but I can't even use Query because I need to specify a value for the primary key, but I want all results with a specific FilterExpression and ordered. I don't want to use PHP to "post-produce" the results to set the order.